# How to set background image fixed while using Horizontal scrollview in ios

Tags: ios, xcode

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"Welcome to Home Page");
    [super viewDidLoad];

   self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-image.png"]];


// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



- (void)loadView {


    CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1400, 100);

    UIImageView *tempImageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sti01.png"]];
    tempImageView2.frame=CGRectMake(10, 60, 200, 200);
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView2];


    UIImageView *tempImageView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sti02.png"]];
    tempImageView3.frame=CGRectMake(240, 60, 200, 200);
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView3];

    UIImageView *tempImageView4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sti03.png"]];
    tempImageView4.frame=CGRectMake(470, 60, 200, 200);
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView4];

    UIImageView *tempImageView5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sti04.png"]];
    tempImageView5.frame=CGRectMake(700, 60, 200, 200);
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView5];


    UIImageView *tempImageView6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sti05.png"]];
    tempImageView6.frame=CGRectMake(930, 60, 200, 200);
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView6];

    UIImageView *tempImageView7 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sti06.png"]];
    tempImageView7.frame=CGRectMake(1160, 60, 200, 200);
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView7];



    self.view=scrollView;
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView2];
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView3];
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView4];
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView5];
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView6];
    [scrollView addSubview:tempImageView7];

    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(22, 100, 1800, 500);
   // [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTest:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
    [scrollView addSubview:btn];


}


- (IBAction)buttonTest:(id)sender {
    MSDescriptionpage *aSecondPageController = [[MSDescriptionpage  alloc] initWithNibName:@"MSDescriptionpage" bundle:nil];        
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aSecondPageController animated:YES];        
    [aSecondPageController release];

}
```

How can i set back ground image fixed when i scroll THE CONTENT USING OF UISCROLLVIEW.How to set background image fixed while using Horizontal scrollview in ios.i using many formats but not issue was fixed..

Comment: Please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11699621/1132951) question for your problem. As this is exact duplicate question

Comment: yes,But in this issue was not fixed...Can u tell the solutions for that..

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

[image]

Now add the IBOutlate for the scrollView like this .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

and in .m file

```
@synthesize scrollView;
```

and in xib Control-Drag from file's Owner to the scrollView to assign the IBOutlate to it

this will looks like this

[image]

Now

Comment: i did not use uiscrollview in xib...just in programatically...Then where i want to use clear colour..Can u tell briefly

Comment: ok then after the alloc init the scrollview use it name and set the background color to [UIColor clearColor] just like this `[scrollDisplay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];` here the scrollDisplay is UIScrollView

Comment: CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];[UIColor clearColor] 
    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1400, 100); i use this but not get output.so background also moved.

Comment: `[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];` will make your scrollview's background as clearColor or say transparant. Put this line after contentSize line

Comment: CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1400, 100);
Now i use like this same error.I dono why its happen like that.

Comment: ok I think you need to make the Scroll View non-opaque with this line of code scrollView.opaque = NO;

Comment: CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]; scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1400, 100); scrollView.opaque = NO; But error not solved...Can u tell in some other way...same error occur again and again

Comment: And if still no luck just put one UIImage below the scrollView and make the frame of image full Screen size

Comment: hi  Aalok Parikh..i dono how to use image below scrollview for background.can u tell this..

Comment: ok got error you have used one line like self.view = scrollView;

Comment: ya i already used that line but not fixed..Now also i used like that but same error.CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]; scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1400, 100); scrollView.opaque = NO;self.view=scrollView;

Comment: you have to add the scrollView as the subview of self.view as `[self.view addSubview:scrollView];` will solve your problem. Have to replace that line with this one

Comment: Also remove the addSubView: lines below it to add the images as it will add them again as it is already added to scroll view

Comment: [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]; scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1400, 100); scrollView.opaque = NO;[self.view addSubview:scrollView]; while use this code means i got error while i run app...

Comment: can u tell how to add this and want to finish this problem..Again and again same problem

Comment: Error is "unable to restore previously selected frame"

Comment: ok Please try to put [self.view addSubview:scrollView]; line at the end of the loadview function does it solve your problem?

Comment: oh man this is ridicules :( !!!! ok now tell me can you use one ScrollView added via xib or you need it just programmatically only?

Comment: ok then drag and drop one scroll view to the view and it will looks like the image i put in answer see edit

Comment: [self.view addSubView:scrollView]; i use this commend means always i got error....

Comment: If your file's owner is UIViewController type then this will not happen as it works with me fine. Check this out is it of the mentioned type ?

Comment: can u provide u r number or mail can we talk straight right now..becoz i want to finish within today night...